# How to use react-router to navigate component with multiple pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Suppose that I have 2 pages and several components. The first page is the login page and the other page is the main menu. The login page only has 1 component. Once the user has logged into the website I want react-router to navigate to the main menu, the main menu has navbar and some components right down below. I want it to be able to navigate to each component and keep the navbar at the top all the time even the URL has been changed.

Here the code I've tried

```
// Inside the root component
<BrowserRouter>
     <Route path="/menu" component={MenuForm}/>
     <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm}/>
</BrowserRouter>

//Inside the menu page component  
<Navbar/>
<Route path="/shop" component={Shop}/>
<Route path="/categories" component={Categories}/>
```

With this code, I can only navigate to menu page and login page, but I can not navigate to Shop and categories which are the child component of main menu

Comment: So the Navbar should be available on both menu and login routes yes?

Comment: no the Navbar should only appear on the main menu

Answer (score 1):

You need to have home page

```
<Route path="/home" component={Home}/> // all your menu and everything here
```

now if from home you want to go to menu
you can do like this

```
<Route path="/home/menu" component={Menu}/>
```

This component will render in  home page where you set nested routes so matching route component will render

```
<Route path="/home/menu" component={menu}/>
<Route path="/home/profile" component={Profile}/>
```

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine, but can it be like path="/menu" or path="/profile" independently.

Comment: yes it will be,  if you want to show the only menu at root level then this is fine

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should consider creating container components. Where the first container will be containing your login routes namely "Auth Container", and the another components should be into the App routes namely "App Container". And you can have your own wrapper.

```
const AppRoutes = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Navigation scrolling={scrolling} />
            <Switch>
                <ProtectedRoute exact path="/profile" component={UserProfile} />
                <ProtectedRoute exact path="/my-orders" component={MyOrders} />
                <ProtectedRoute path="/my-saved-result" component={SavedResults} />
            </Switch>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `react-router v4`, you could you `Switch` component to declaratively define your routes like below:

```
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const MenuForm = () => (
  <div className="app-routes">
    <NavBar />
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/menu">
      <Redirect to="/menu/shop" />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/menu/shop" component={Shop} />
      <Route path="/menu/categories" component={Categories} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: What if you have `/login` & `/password-reset` route which doesn't have `<NavBar>` Could you show how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using like this

```
    <div className="main-panel">
        <Navbar />
        <div className="content" style={{ backgroundColor: '#f4f3ef' }}>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                <Route path="/reports" component={ReportMain} />
                <Route path="/showWebService" component={ShowWebService} />
            </Switch>
        </div>         
    </div>
```

The navbar is static when you navigate to link its only getting these component render.

```
<Link to="/reports">
  <p>Reports</p>
</Link>
```

Call component with Link